# Можно ли каким-то образом доставать информацию частями из ResultSet?

Tags: java

В `ResultSet` имею примерно сто тысяч строк, в каждой из которой имеется 3 параметра: `id`, `fName`, `lName`, теперь всю эту информацию нужно передать внешнему API для дальнейшей обработки. И для того что бы все это дело работало быстро и не рухнуло на продакшене нужно это сделать частями. Ну или другим способом, который я пока не могу найти.

Каким способом возможно извлечь иформацию частями как можно эффективнее?
Можно ли сделать например

```
result.getDataFromRow(<Num of start row>, <Num of end row>)
```

Comment: Что вы имеет в виду под "извлечь информацию частями"? Извлечь определенные строки? Или извлечь значения из определенных ячеек?

Comment: С помощью SQL запроса я получаю огромное кол-во данных (значения) которые находятся в ResultSet. И вот тут возникает проблема..

Comment: Так в чем проблема-то? Опишите нормально: какие данные получаете, что именно хотите извлечь.

Comment: В ResultSet имею примерно сто тысяч строк, в каждой из которой имеется 3 параметра: id, fName, lName, теперь всю эту информацию нужно передать внешнему API для дальнейшей обработки. И для того что бы все это дело работало быстро и не рухнуло на продакшене нужно это сделать частями. Ну или другим способом, который я пока немогу найти.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильный подход к проблеме. Если вам нужна только часть данных из `ResultSet`, то напишите правильный запрос, который вернет вам нужный объем. Если же вам все же нужно обработать все данные, то сделайте это в несколько запросов.